# MSP430 SD card using an i2c interface

Tags: msp430

I want to connect an SD card or USB using the `I2C interface of MSP430`. 
Here the hardware part is correct in my design, however I could not send any data to the SD card.

For debugging ; how could I send data to the SD card?

The data should be received from the `ADC12MEM` registers and just need to be written in the SD card. From this source code above, there is no process, when I debug and I could not send any user input to the SD card.

Comment: You want to send data to the SD card for debugging? If yes, then may I suggest that you send your debug messages out on the serial port. Use a 3.3V TTL to USB converter and log your messages on the PC.

There is no source code in your question!

Answer (score 1):

SD cards use the SPI protocol for communication, so I2C won't work.

When you get the SPI interface working you may want to take a look at FatFS: http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html

Answer (score 1):

SD cards starts always in SD mode, which is not suitable for an SPI interface. You need to follow a proper protocol to set them in SPI mode, before you can write any data.

Take a look at the **SD Card Specification** from SanDisk or any other manufacturer to obtain details on how to enable SPI mode.